# moment js displays milliseconds after AM/PM

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-formatting

Currently working on a project that deals with different languages and ran into a weird behavior when displaying milliseconds in the PM/AM format.

If I want to display a date/time pair with millisecond precision using the AM/PM format I get something like this:

```
12/14/2017 3:45:45 PM.199
```

Whereas the same date/time in a 24h format is shown like this:

```
12/14/2017 15:45:45.199
```

Is there a way to display the AM/PM format like this:

```
12/14/2017 3:45:45.199 PM
```

The objective is to dislpay the date/time according to the users localization options, that is why I'm using the "L LTS" formatting.

[Here is a fiddle to illustrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/w85gc53q/17/)

```
var divEn = $('#divEn');
var divFi = $('#divFi');
var en = "en";
var pt = "pt";
var dateEn = moment().locale(en);
var dateFi = moment().locale(pt);
format = "L LTS.SSS";
divEn.text(dateEn.format(format));
divFi.text(dateFi.format(format));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you always want to display result like `12/14/2017 3:45:45.199 PM` use `MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss.SSS A` as [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) token instead of `L LTS.SSS`.

`MM` stands for number of month, `DD` is day of the month, `YYYY` is the year, `h` is the hour (0..12), `mm` stands for minutes, `ss` stands for seconds, `SSS` stands for fractional second and `A` stands for AM/PM.

`L` and `LTS` are localized tokens (output varies based on locale).

**EDIT:**

You can use [`localeData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat()` go get localized format token, then you can check if the `LTS` token contains the AM/PM token (`A` or `a`) and change the format dinamically.

Here a live sample:

```js
function getCustomLocalizedFormat(locale){
  var localeData = moment.localeData(locale);
  var lts = localeData.longDateFormat('LTS');
  var format = "L LTS.SSS";
  if( lts.match(/a/i) ){
    format = "L h:mm:ss.SSS A";
  }
  return format;
}

var divEn = $('#divEn');
var divFi = $('#divFi');
var divRes = $('#divRes');
var en = "en";
var pt = "pt";
var dateEn = moment().locale(en);
var dateFi = moment().locale(pt);

var enLocaleData = moment.localeData('en');
var formatEn = getCustomLocalizedFormat('en');
var formatPt = getCustomLocalizedFormat('pt');

divEn.text(dateEn.format(formatEn));
divFi.text(dateFi.format(formatPt));
divRes.text(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss.SSS A'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<p>English</p>
<div id="divEn"></div> 
<p>Portuguese</p>
<div id="divFi"></div>
<p>General</p>
<div id="divRes"></div>
```

Please note that:

- This approach is not test for each locale supported by momentjs. Locales like `pa-in`(Punjabi), `ml` (Malayalam), `ne` (Nepalese), `hi` (Hindi), `gom-latn` (Konkani Latin script) and others have the `LTS` token that starts with `A`. It's not clear to me what is the your expected output for these locales.
- You can customize [Long Date Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/) using `updateLocale` function and the `longDateFormat` key.

Probably the best approach is to define a subset of supported locales and define custom format for each locale (and/or just customized moment's `LTS`).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. 

I have edited the question to better explain the problem. The reason why i'm using the "L LTS" is because I want the time to be displayed according to the users language preferences.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I fear it's impossible to provide a solution that works for each locale, anyway it's important to define what is your expected output.